# in what cases is possible re-adding a disk previously removed with mdadm?

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid

Let's say that I have the following ARRAY:

```
mdadm  -Q --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Oct 29 17:35:52 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 8382464 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 8382464 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Oct 30 07:29:40 2021
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : debian:0  (local to host debian)
              UUID : 423096f2:994556ee:1a3ff40e:75475fc5
            Events : 317

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
```

Then, I simulate a failure and remove the failing disk:

```
mdadm  /dev/md0 --verbose --fail /dev/sde1
mdadm: set /dev/sde1 faulty in /dev/md0
mdadm /dev/md0  --verbose --remove  /dev/sde1
mdadm: hot removed /dev/sde1 from /dev/md0
```

This is the metadata of Arrays components:

```
mdadm  -E  /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 423096f2:994556ee:1a3ff40e:75475fc5
           Name : debian:0  (local to host debian)
  Creation Time : Fri Oct 29 17:35:52 2021
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 16764928 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
     Array Size : 8382464 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
    Data Offset : 10240 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=10160 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 701db404:61dbf37b:933d61d0:42b02759

    Update Time : Sat Oct 30 07:30:15 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 6739499b - correct
         Events : 328


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

mdadm  -E  /dev/sde1
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 423096f2:994556ee:1a3ff40e:75475fc5
           Name : debian:0  (local to host debian)
  Creation Time : Fri Oct 29 17:35:52 2021
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 16764928 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
     Array Size : 8382464 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
    Data Offset : 10240 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=10160 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 779a1bbf:68684dcc:6efb0c73:af2c0759

    Update Time : Sat Oct 30 07:29:40 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 14848dc8 - correct
         Events : 317


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

But if I try to re-add this what it happens:

```
mdadm /dev/md0  --verbose --re-add  /dev/sde1
mdadm: --re-add for /dev/sde1 to /dev/md0 is not possible
```

However, I can --add without problems

The man pages states:

> However based on the event count on the device, the recovery may only require sections that are flagged a write-intent bitmap to be recovered or may not require any recovery at all.

I don't fully understand what that means. For example in which cases the event count is close enough to re-adding to be possible?

I've found that even stopping and assembling the array is not possible either (I mean the array start but as "degraded")

So could you explain me in what cases is possible re-adding a disk previously removed?

Comment: you can try `--re-add missing` or `--re-add faulty` but, mdadm just doesn't like explicitely fail removed drives, for as to why you'd have to ask the mdadm devs, I guess